# Paint Text field implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, annotations, html5-canvas, mouseevent

Is it possible to implement the paint text feature in javascript on a canvas?

A text button say "A" ,on click of this like in paint one should be able to draw a text box on canvas wherever the user clicked mouse.Also should be able to type text init.Also should be able to move this text box anywhere on the canvas.

Any suggestion/solution is appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basic framework should get you started.

This code allows the user to enter their text.

Then they click on the canvas and their text is drawn at the mouse position.

Of course, you will want to take it from here to design it to fit your needs.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7GHvj/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var lastX;
    var lastY;
    var strokeColor="red";
    var strokeWidth=2;
    var canMouseX;
    var canMouseY;
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#downlog").html("Down: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      var text=document.getElementById("text").value;
      ctx.font = 'italic 20px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillText(text,canMouseX,canMouseY);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>


    <p>Enter the text here first</p> 
    <input id="text" type="text" name="text" value="My Text."><br>
    <p>Then click on the canvas to draw the text.</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=576 height=307></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the reply.This is really helpful.I will try to modify this according to my requirement.:-)